# no method matching in subtraction

Tags: julia

I'm using julia 0.5 after run this code :

```
Freqsample = 100;
second = 4;
step = (Freqsample * second )-1
```

i get this Error :

```
MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Int64, ::Colon, ::UnitRange{Int64})
 in -(::Int64, ::Int64) at main.jl:12
 in include_string(::String, ::String) at loading.jl:441
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at boot.jl:234
 in (::Atom.##65#68)() at eval.jl:40
 in withpath(::Atom.##65#68, ::Void) at utils.jl:30
 in withpath(::Function, ::Void) at eval.jl:46
 in macro expansion at eval.jl:109 [inlined]
 in (::Atom.##64#67{Dict{String,Any}})() at task.jl:60
```

Whats wrong with subtracting ? i'm pretty new to julia forgive if its a dumb question

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I get `julia> step = (Freqsample * second )-1
399`. Maybe you have overwritten some definition somewhere. What happens if you restart Julia and try again?

Comment: Also, FYI step is a function used for getting the step size of a range so think twice before assigning a variable to the same name.

Comment: Re: `step` – shouldn't matter, that's what scope and namespaces are for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've redefined `-` for more types than you probably intended. The second line in the backtrace you posted is telling you that Julia called a `-` method in `main.jl` for two integers. And line one is saying that within there it's trying to do something like `x[:, 1:5]` at line 12, where `x` is an integer.

This tells me two things;

1. Your definition of `-` is probably typed too permissively. You probably didn't intend to accept integers.
2. You are probably *shadowing* the built in `-` definition instead of extending it. You need to `import Base: -` in order to add a new method to a function in the standard library.