# Julia: No method matching overloaded parse()

Tags: julia

I'm very new to Julia (as in today). I'm trying to use a package `AutoEnvs` which uses the [AutomotiveDrivingModels](https://github.com/sisl/AutomotiveDrivingModels.jl) package but when I run `using AutoEnvs` I get this error

`MethodError: no method matching parse(::Type{AutomotiveDrivingModels.LaneConnection}, ::SubString{String})`

In the problem code in the AutomotiveDrivingModels package they do the following

1. Define `struct LaneConnection`
2. Define `function Base.parse(::Type{LaneConnection}, line::String)`
3. Define `function advance!()`
4. In a loop, `conn = parse(LaneConnection, advance!())` - this throws the error

I tried using `::Type{AutomotiveDrivingModels.LaneConnection}` in the definition of `Base.parse` and also adding the package name in the call to `parse` but it didn't help.

Based on the error it looks like `advance!()` is returning a `SubString` - could this be the problem if the overloaded `parse()` is expecting `String`?

I also tried adding `import Base: parse` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947095/no-method-matching-in-subtraction) but it didn't help.

By the way, this is all to try and install [ngsim_env](https://github.com/sisl/ngsim_env). Note, [the installation instructions](https://github.com/sisl/ngsim_env/blob/master/docs/install_env_gail_full.md) require an older version of AutomotiveDrivingModels at a specific commit.

System:

Mac OS Mojave 10.14 (installed xcode command-line tools)
Julia: v0.7.0 (restriction of ngsim_env installation)

Thank you!

**EDIT**

At one point restarting the interpreter and trying `using AutoEnvs` again resolved this error. But I just had to do a fresh installation and changed some other package versions and now this error is back and restarting does not help anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On master the signature of `Base.parse` is:

```
function Base.parse(::Type{LaneConnection}, line::AbstractString)
```

and it should work as expected. You can check it here https://github.com/sisl/AutomotiveDrivingModels.jl/blob/master/src/2d/roadway/roadways.jl#L45.

You can install this version of the package by adding `#master` suffix to package name when doing `add` in package manager.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the function signature, it helped me resolve the issue. I have to use an earlier version of AutomotiveDrivingModels because of other restrictions and the older version expects `line::String`. But the error shows the call to `parse()` is passing `SubString`. New to julia so wasn't sure how to resolve that without breaking other calls. I just updated `parse()` to expect `line:AbstractString` and that seems to work.